# Unable to load crypto library. Failed with error:~n\"~p, ~s\"~n~s

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to execute **Elixir code** in local machine via **AWS Lambda**. Whenever I tried to run the code, the error gets as mentioned below.

```erlang
args: [load_failed,"Failed to load NIF library /var/task/lib/crypto-4.5/priv/lib/crypto: 'libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'","OpenSSL might not be installed on this system.\n"]
    format: "Unable to load crypto library. Failed with error:~n\"~p, ~s\"~n~s"
    label: {error_logger,error_msg}
```

Could anyone help me to solve the error!

Comment: I could not understand what you are trying to execute where via what, but there definitely should be `libcrypto` installed.

Comment: Thanks for replying. My code is

`def create_user(attrs, context) when is_map(attrs) and is_map(context) do
        # %SampleEcto.Users{}
        # |> changeset(attrs)
        # |> Repo.insert()
        """
        Sample Ecto!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        Request: #{Kernel.inspect(attrs)}
        Context: #{Kernel.inspect(context)}
        """
        |> IO.puts
        :ok
        
   end`
I am trying to execute this code in **AWS Lambda**. The source link is [here](https://hexdocs.pm/aws_lambda_elixir_runtime/readme.html)

Comment: I have already installed **libssl-dev** @AlekseiMatiushkin